# Hibernate : org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, jpa

I have deployed REST Services (Jersey) on Google App Engine. I'm using Hibernate 4.2.0 as JPA with MySQL Database. My application runs perfectly fine when I run it on my local system. But gives the following error if I deploy it and run on Google App Engine:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:238)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:439)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
```

These are the jars that are part of build path:

[image]

jars in my lib folder:
[image]

Comment: issue is with conflicting `JPA` jars.

Comment: also post your `pom.xml`

Comment: I'm not using Maven for this; so no pom.xml!

Answer (score 0):

Since 'NONE' is new in `JPA2`, I suspect you also have `JPA1` on your `classpath` somewhere. Find and remove it.

Now there is a support for `JPA 1.0` and `JPA 2.0` in `GAE`.

Have a look to configure `JPA 2.0` [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2) and [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview).

Comment: I tried trial and error method to find the jar thats causing the issue and I see that I included only the necessary jars. I'm unable to figure out which jar belongs to JPA1 in my class path. Any idea how I can find the jar that belongs to JPA1 (just incase if I'm missing)?

Comment: @SuperStar what are the jars inside `war/WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: @SuperStar local which server.??

Comment: I don't use any server in local such as Tomcat or Glassfish. I just run it as Google App which is connected to MySQL on my local machine (I use MAMP for this though). I have also installed Eclipse GAE plugin.